# "Nice and easy does the trick" VS "Nicely and easily does the trick"

Tags: phrase-usage

> “Nice and easy does the trick, Potter,” he growled.

I feel "Nicely and easily does the trick" is correct, because "nicely and easily" modifies the verb 'does'. I'm wondering why the author wrote "Nice and easy does the trick" instead? Is it a colloquial usage?

Comment: I don't think these are adverbial modifiers of **does** but predicate adjectives in an elliptical construction with "manner" being understood . A manner that is nice and easy is called for.  Not that the word **manner** has been dropped; but what is missing is that which can be modified by the adjectives "nice and easy".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You meant it can be construed as: Potter does the trick in a nice and easy manner. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: No.  First, "To do the trick" means "to succeed, to suffice".   *It was coming loose but a bit of duct tape did the trick.*   A piece of tape secured it sufficiently.  What I'm saying is that we can understand the sentence as saying "a manner that is nice and easy will suffice here", rather than expecting the adverbs **nicely and easily** as you do, modifying **does**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I now see your point. *The nice and easy manner suffices to do the trick*, right?

Comment: Yes, a [ ... ] that can have **nice and easy** predicated of it does the trick.  Or *You being | acting | behaving nice and easy does the trick*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Does it imply that to Potter, it's easy to win the game?

Comment: No. It is advice to proceed not too aggressively.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But actually It's been said after the game.

Comment: Then it is after-the-fact advice. The meaning doesn't change. I haven't read the books and you haven't given any context. Compare *Slow and steady wins the race*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  "Nice and easy" is a colloquial phrase that is common in this context.

"Nice and easily" is probably more grammatical but no one says it.

Comment: Is it also regional?

Comment: Don't think so. It's pretty ubiquitous. Certainly common in the US and UK.

Comment: Do you have other examples off the top of your head?

Comment: Whoa, pardner.  Easy does it.

Comment: "probably more grammatical but no one says it" is a contradiction.

Comment: Not at all a contradiction.  Many colloquial phrases are not perfectly grammatical and many grammatical alternatives are rarely or never used. Grammar is a set of rules, not a list of what is commonly said.

Comment: Grammar is a codified description of what is said. It's not *a priori*.

Comment: Your understanding of the nature of grammar does not agree with what the rest of us understand it to be.  Glad you have a system of beliefs to cling to, though.

Comment: @farnsy:  Read up on the difference between "prescriptive" and "descriptive" grammar.